# RowFilter: dataGridView rows disappearing after edit

Tags: c#, datagridview, rowfilter

I have a dataGridView that I populate with a RowFilter:

```
    private void ResultsFunc()
    {
        ColumnToSearch = comboBox1.Text;

        if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            ToSearchBy = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        else if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            ToSearchBy = textBox1.Text;
        }

        dt = aSH_ORDER_DBDataSet.ASH_PROD_ORDERS;
        dv = new DataView(dt);

        dv.RowFilter = ColumnToSearch + " = " + "'" + ToSearchBy + "'";

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
    }
```

When I edit the parameter I searched on in one of the returned rows they disappear from the dataGridView, is there a way I can stop that from happening?

I want to still see the row after I edit the value.

Comment: Do you only populate the gridview in this function(resultsfunc)?

Comment: @dan6657 no i also populate it at run time with this: aSH_PROD_ORDERSTableAdapter.Fill(aSH_ORDER_DBDataSet.ASH_PROD_ORDERS);

Comment: I'm guessing they probably don't, but do the two populations cancel each other out?

Also does your resultsFunc run from pageload?

Comment: Yes if i run Resultsfunc, it will clear the view and only display the results, and vice versa. Resultsfunc will only display when a user clicks the search button

Comment: Most likely need to populate the grid in pageload too refer to answer below, ask more questions if you have about this answer!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is most likely because when you edit the parameter - PageLoad is called which runs the PageLoad(); function (kind of refreshing the page) without running all of the other functions which rely on onclicks(which populate the table)

To combat this you would most likely need to populate the gridview in the pageload alongside the function, or just call the function from pageload too.

Using a public static variable to store the current value of the parameter in your onclick(or wherever the parameter is set), then passing this parameter to your pageload populating the data with the current parameter selected..

Comment: I think you are correct is saying that after the value is edited it refreshes the page, and any my RowFilter is applied again. 

I am not sure how i would use page load, where could i find that function?

Comment: The Pageload function should have been at the start of your c# class if that's where you kept it - protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Oh sorry, this is a WFP so it's Form_load and it only runs once when the program is started.

Comment: Ah okay, it seems like it's updating/refreshing without your population somewhere though so you'll need to find where and populate your grid there too i'm guessing.